# perforce unshelving in other branch with partial mapping

Tags: perforce, p4v, unshelve, perforce-branch-spec

Let's say I've shelved files A,B,C
I now want to unshelf this into a different branch, but my spec only has files A,B

Is there any way to do this so that perforce will unshelf the files that are mapped and ignore the rest? Right now I get an error which prevents me from doing any unshelving.

The use case here is I have one branch where I compile a third party lib, and I'd like to move over just the binaries and the public header changes. This changelist is huge so I'd rather not have to manually shelf only what is mapped.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge I don't think you can use shelving to move changes from one branch to another.  That would be a Merge/Copy depending on the situation.

Using shelving to do that would be a bypass of the (not saying malicious or intentional)  versioning process.